# Help with these graphics in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, tikz-graphdrawing, draw

I need draw these graphs in tikz, but i not have idea by begin :(

The graphs are:

1. Variation of ionization cross-sections (left)
2. Townsend first ionization coefficient (right)

Help pls... Ty :D

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: You listed pgfplots in your tags.  Have you looked at the manual?

Comment: Please do not cross-post without linking. Doing this disrespects others by treating their time and efforts as of no value, so that it is of no significance if people spend time duplicating a solution already provided elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was cross-posted to [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org). I posted my answer there: [How can I plot ionization graphs in TikZ](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=29141). Here it is too:

With `pgfplots` we can easily design the axes. Then we can draw the points with experimental data. The `smooth` option gives a smoother connection, like interpolated. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width = 6cm, compat = newest}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{
  tick label style = { font=\tiny\sansmath\sffamily},
  label style      = { font=\small\sansmath\sffamily}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
      domain = 0:100,
      xlabel     = Electron energy,
      ylabel     = Ionization,
      axis lines = left,
      clip       = false, 
      xmin = 0,  xmax = 100,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 100,
      xtick={32,65},
      xticklabels={$10^1$,$10^2$},
      ytick={40,80},
      yticklabels={$10^1$,$10^2$},
    ]
    \addplot [smooth, dashed]
      coordinates { (5,4) (7,40) (10,60) (14,74) (20,84) (30,90)
                    (40,90) (50,87) (60,81) (65,76)};
    \addplot [smooth]
      coordinates { (8,10) (9,44) (12,64) (14,72) (20,82) (30,87)
                    (40,88) (50,85) (60,79) (65,74)};
    \addplot [smooth]
      coordinates { (10,5) (9,20) (9.3,40) (12,61) (15,69.5) (20,75) (30,77)
                    (40,73) (50,66) (60,58) (65,54)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]

To get plots similar to your image, I placed your plot at the background of this plot, added a temporary fine grid, and chose coordinates that match the image. I could use more points to get it closer to the original, but that doesn't really matter for the explanation. At the end I removed the original image and the grid and added custom labels.